# What does it mean if a neural network uses the max number of training iterations? Is a network poorly set up if it does?

Tags: neural-network, iteration

I'm currently adjusting the inputs I include for a neural network I'm making to do classification work. For many of the combinations I've used so far, it has gone through 1000 iterations (the max allowed in my set up).

One of the new input combinations I've tried is consistently stopping after 20-50 iterations. Accuracy wise it is performing better (still not stellar, but somewhat better on average and considerably more consistent).

How do I best interpret this? That inputs included in those other combinations were distracting for the system? If two networks are similar accuracy wise but one stops after say 20 iterations while the other uses the maximum allowed is the former superior?

Comment: It seems your learning-framework is doing early-stopping. There is no general rule as everything can happen. If the accuracy is the same, one might say: they are equally good, no matter how they achieved this. Of course one could assume, that the one using less iterations might generalize better, but this could be wrong or right. Improving cross-validation (more folds for example) could help to improve this analysis.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to say a neural network is inferior if it uses more iterations (aka 'epochs') other than it took less time to build.  To some that may be enough of a reason but once a model is built, comparisons come down to accuracy (RMSE, AUC, etc.) and perhaps complexity where it may impact speed of predictions.

A neural network could use all iterations simply because it has not yet converged (i.e. more information is found).  In this case, letting the network train longer would be a good thing.

That said, if a network trains for too long it could overfit.  This is precisely why 'early stopping' is often applied.  In essence it basically says that I want to stop my network from learning after it stops learning information (user defined threshold).

To answer your question directly ("**How do I interpret this?**") - Without any further information it appears your network is learning the necessary information quite quickly and training for the full number of iterations is resulting in some slight overfitting.